# Combination of map() and filter()

Tags: python

I just had an idea that I find pretty intriguing: A combination between map() and filter() using generator as predicate and `yield from`. To make it short, here's the code:

```
def map_filter(function, iterable):
    """convert and filter a sequence"""
    for i in iterable:
        yield from function(i)
```

Now, what's the deal? Basically, this is a combination between the aforementioned two functions which incorporates both their functionality. Actually, the possibility to pass additional parameters to `map()` is still missing, though that's a minor detail IMHO and it could be extended for that. Here's a comparison, generating squares of numbers:

```
def function(x):
    return x * x
res = map(function, range(0, 10))
print(list(res))

def function(x):
    yield x * x
res = map_filter(function, range(0, 10))
print(list(res))
```

Here's another, filtering odd numbers:

```
def function(x):
    return x % 2 == 1
res = filter(function, range(0, 10))
print(list(res))

def function(x):
    if x % 2 == 1:
        yield x
res = map_filter(function, range(0, 10))
print(list(res))
```

And the last one, combining the two above:

```
def function1(x):
    return x * x
def function2(x):
    return x % 2 == 1
res = map(function1, filter(function2, range(0, 10)))
print(list(res))

def function(x):
    if x % 2 == 1:
        yield x * x
res = map_filter(function, range(0, 10))
print(list(res))
```

Notes and questions:

- First question of course, am I reinventing the wheel or would this be a useful addition to Python (e.g. in itertools)?
- Are there any problems or downsides to this? One I see is the slightly more complex interface, but it seems a useful tool for general sequence manipulation.
- `map_filter()` requires a generator (with `yield`), so I can't use `lambda` with it (Can I?). For very small filtering/mapping functions, the amount of code is larger therefore, but otherwise you can probably write more terse code using a combined filtering/mapping function.
- One of the best selling points is that not only can you use `map_filter()` to remove elements from a sequence, but you can also use it to inject additional elements.
- I'm of course open for any suggestions or improvements.

Comment: This generally goes by names like "flatmap", since it's a composition of flatten and map. With itertools, you'd generally do `chain.from_iterable(map(whatever, whatever))`.

Comment: excuse my ignorance: from [what I read](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) `yield from` takes values from a generator, not a simple function. Otherwise you might just do `yield function(i)`

Comment: A generator is just a function (created with `def ...`) that uses `yield` instead of `return`, @Pynchia.

Comment: Just returning in the function allows you to  `yield from map(function, iterable)` which is in my opinion a lot nicer that an explicit for loop

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt are you saying any function returning a value supports the iteration protocol? I have just tried your code: it does not work (function is `return x * x`)

Comment: @Pynchia, you need to be using a generator function. `yield x * x`

Comment: Your last example could be re-written as: `res = (x * x for x in range(0, 10) if x % 2)`

Comment: Those were just examples, @Peter. For more complex scenarios, the form you propose does not create readable (IMHO, of course) code.

Answer (score 5):

You can define generator expressions:

```
>>> values = range(0, 10)
>>> evens = (value for value in values if not value % 2)
>>> even_squares = (even * even for even in evens)
>>> list(even_squares)
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```

Comment: this can be shortened with `list((value*value for value in range(0, 10) if value % 2==0))`

Comment: I mean you don't need two generator expressions

Comment: But that's what the question is about, how to combine multiple filters and transformations, not how to rewrite it as a one-liner.

Comment: even then, you always go filter and map, but never filter and filter or map and map, so each filter and map can be done using one generator expression, it is not about one liner.

Comment: It's an example of what you can do without having to combine into a one-liner. If you were using it could combine however you liked.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions with conditional instead. For example:

```py
squared_evens = [n*n for n in range(10) if n % 2 == 0]
```

```
squared_evens
>>> [0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```

Comment: This is different because it has no lazy evaluation. If your list might be infinite, use a generator